# In App Purchases reinstalling bypass android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, reinstall

I am developing an application where the user can select 2 out of 4 items for free and the other 2 items are purchasable.

It just occured to me that with this strategy, it would be very easy for the user to reinstall the app and then select the 2 other options he had not selected before in order to get access to the full content.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Then make 2 spcific item free and 2 specific item purchasable

Comment: This is a possibility, but since I would like to target the user's preferences first, it would be preferable for me to give them the choice of their selection.

I know that in app-purchases are tied to the google account, so maybe there's a way of making the first 2 a "free", kind of pseudo-in-app-purchase?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, you have to maintain your own server to keep the database of used items of a particular user.

When he reinstalls the app, fetch records of that particular user from your server and check for the feature access.

Or otherwise allow the user to avail all the 4 features at a time [2 Free , 2 Paid]. Thus, when he reinstalls the app, you can query google regarding the purchased items.